# What science data has been released from Chang'e 4?

Tags: the-moon, scientific-data, chang-e

[Chang'e 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang%27e_4) was the first soft landing on the far side of the moon. What science data has been released from it? That is, in two parts: what science was done and of that, what data has been released to the public?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it hints that more data might be forthcoming. They mention [Emily Lakdawalla and the Planetary Society](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/)  Phys.org: [China shares stunning new moon photos with the world](https://phys.org/news/2016-02-china-stunning-moon-photos-world.html)

Comment: Relevant: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-019-1189-0

Comment: Yes indeed! It's paywalled but there is more information at Phys.org's [China's Chang'E 4 mission discovers new 'secrets' from the far side of the moon](https://phys.org/news/2019-05-china-mission-secrets-side-moon.html) and The Planetary Society's Andrew Jones' blogpost [Chang’e-4 may have discovered material from the Moon’s mantle](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/guest-blogs/2019/change-4-may-have-discovered.html)